# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes randomly 14.04 New Problem

Tags: 14.04

I have installed Ubuntu on 16 core machine. I have worked on the machine for about a month with no issues, however, the PC starts to freeze randomly for no reason. Furthermore, from time to time after restarting, it gives the following message;

> kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout: not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler
>
> kernel Offset: disabled

I am not quite sure what is going on with the operating system. I would appreciate any insight.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: kernel panic is the same as a blue screen of death. Basically,  you're having a hardware or software failure that the system does not know how to solve. Kernal panics are mostly hardware failures though, I'd start by doing memtests.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I have tested all memories and all of them are passed the test. I have tested the hard drive and is passed as well. Now, I did a test where I used only one processor at a time. Everything works perfectly.  However, When I put both processors together, the operating system freezes again. Could this be a bug in Ubuntu 14.04 LTC? Knowing that I used the same OS for a month with no issues at all?